# subset of python set based on string methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

Given the following set:

```
s = {"brown", "blue", "Blue", "green", "red", "black"}
```

how do you pull subsets out of it with Python string methods?

For example the following applied to one string, if they could be applied to the whole set, would pull out different subsets:

```
"brown".startswith("b")
"Blue".lower().startswith("b")
"e" in "green"
```

I have unique, unordered lists, ie sets, and am wondering if this kind of operation can be neatly carried out on a Python set so I can avoid writing list comprehensions.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Set comprehensions exist.

Comment: Oh yes, of course, forgot about them.. and am guessing there is no shorter way of doing it then?

Comment: No shorter way? how short do you want?

Comment: Thanks, well I think it won't go any shorter unless you defined a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for a set comprehension like such:

```
subset = {sub for sub in s if sub.startswith('b')}
```

This can also be done using `filter` and `operator.methodcaller`

```
from operator import methodcaller as call

subset = set(filter(call('startswith', 'b'), s))
```

If legibility isn't an option you could use set unpacking: `{*iterable}`

So a method could look like:

```
def findall(s, find, meth = 'startswith')
    return {*filter(call(meth, find), s)}

findall(s, 'b')
#{'blue', 'brown', 'black'}
```

Comment: @cardamom I added another option using filter that is a little shorter *(if you alias methodcaller)* and if you don't need it as a set afterwards just leave `set()` out too